# Returning Multiple Views in ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I have a checkbox list, with the following options

Option A
Option B
Option C

If the user select Option A, it must return View A, if the user select Option B, it must return View B and so on.

But here is the catch - if the user select Option A and Option B together, it must return View A in one tab and View B in one tab.

Is this possible, or how will I be able to archive this?

I am using MVC 5 with Razor

Comment: it can be achieved by partial views

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can open a new tab from the controller action, as this needs to be done client side, but if what you've specified is the extent of your problem, then this can be achieve simply in jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#theButton').click(function() {
            var a = $('#checkboxA').prop('checked');
            var b = $('#checkboxB').prop('checked');
            var c = $('#checkboxC').prop('checked');

            if (a && b) {
                window.open('/Home/A', '_blank');
                window.location ='/Home/B';
            } else if (a) {
                window.location = '/Home/A';
            } else if (b) {
                window.location = '/Home/B';
            } else if (c) {
                window.location = '/Home/C';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Partial Views as @ashik suggested - worked perfect